# Unable to move cursor to position 0 in Titanium.UI.TextArea

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

- I have a TextArea in a modal Window. When the modal window is displayed, I want the focus to be set to this TextArea. I also want the TextArea to have default text when it is displayed & the cursor to be at the beginning of this text.
- I call focus() on TextArea when modal window is displayed & in the focus() handler, I set the text that I want & call setSelection(0, 0) to move the cursor to position 0.
- This doesn't seem to be working as the cursor remains at the end of the set text.
- I am using the latest version of the SDK.
- It would be great if someone could help me fix this issue. Thanks!

Titanium SDK: 3.0.2 Target platform: IOS only

Here's the code:

```
// 'statusUpdateArea' is my TextArea

$.tabbedBarNav.addEventListener('click',function(e) 
{
   statusUpdateArea.focus();
}

statusUpdateArea.addEventListener('focus',function() 
{
   statusUpdateArea.setValue(" -  I am here'");

   //API to set cursor at beginning doesn't work!!!!!! [or I don'tknow how to use it :(   ]
   statusUpdateArea.setSelection(0, 0);

});
```

Comment: Can you provide your code so that we can easily understand your problem

Comment: Have you tried setting the selection after a slight delay?

Comment: Updated the question with code.

Comment: @DawsonToth .. No, I haven't tried that. But is it necessary? Shouldn't the APIs given in the docs work as is? I'll try setting an interval & let you know if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: One thing to note is that the text gets updated correctly, but cursor remains at the end ie. after 'here'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't focus. setSelection will focus the text area for you. Focusing is preventing the selection from being properly set. Uncomment the .focus call to see it not work.

Try the following. It works for me on iOS with Titanium SDK 3.x.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
});
var textArea = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
    value: 'Some text.'
});
win.add(textArea);
win.addEventListener('open', function(evt) {
    // textArea.focus();
    textArea.setSelection(0, 0);
});
win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hintText for default..You cant set the text like that.. actual setSelection is not for cusor movement . it is used to select a part of value in text field...so u cant use that method...use hint text and let the user to type ..later on u can add the default text to value of text feild it might be useful..

Comment: TextArea does not support hintText on iOS. Only TextField does. This answer is platform dependent. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextArea-property-hintText

Comment: @Sundar: That's an incorrect statement. We can set text of TextArea using setText(). Also, have a look at the documentation of setSelection(). It is the recommended way for moving cursor to 0th position. I am not sure why it's not working for IOS.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this on the Appcelerator dev forum. There seems to be a bug with the implementation on IOS:

[Appcelerator Dev forum](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148692/unable-to-move-cursor-to-position-0-in-titaniumuitextarea#answer-257392)